# replace string in pattern using shell command: sed, awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

Say I have a text file like this:

```
a;bc;d;{a;b;cd}
ab;cde;f;{ab;c;defg}
ab;{a;b;cd};cde;f
...
```

and I want to replace all the semicolons **in curly brackets** by comma. It will look like this after substitution:

```
a;bc;d;{a,b,cd}
ab;cde;f;{ab,c,defg}
ab;{a,b,cd};cde;f
...
```

How should I do it in shell command? sed, awk or whatever...

Comment: Are the curly brackets well-balanced or nested?

Answer (score 5):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 's/({.*?})/ $1 =~ s=;=,=gr /ge' input
```

The problem is your expected output is wrong:

```
a;b;cd         a;b;cd
  |               |
  V               V
a,b,c,d         ab,cd
```

Answer (score 4):

Through perl which uses [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html),

```
$ perl -pe 's/;(?=[^{}]*})/,/g' file
a;bc;d;{a,b,cd}
ab;cde;f;{ab,c,defg}
ab;{a,b,cd};cde;f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':a; s/\(.*\)\({\)\([^;]*\)\(;\)\([^}]*}.*\)/\1\2\3,\5/;t a' file
```

put a label in the beginning and section off hold patterns and loops around until no more successful substitutions on each line (t a)

```
E.g.  
a;bc;d;{a;b;cd}morestuff{bsdj;dsfkjl;sdkjl;kd}
ab;cde;f;{ab;c;defg}
ab;{a;b;cd};cde;f

Output: 
a;bc;d;{a,b,cd}morestuff{bsdj,dsfkjl,sdkjl,kd}
ab;cde;f;{ab,c,defg}
ab;{a,b,cd};cde;f
```